# Training Tesseract-ocr 4.0 LSTM on windows7 / windows10

Tags: windows, tesseract, lstm

[TrainingTesseract-4.00](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/TrainingTesseract-4.00) introduce the way to train LSTM on linux, a few of tools and libraries need to install.

How to embark on training the LSTM engine on windows??

Does anybody know the steps?

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling#windows